# Butterknife not working with ViewFlipper

Tags: android, butterknife

This is a bit strange. Butterknife seems to be working with all other Views except my ViewFlipper. My ViewFlipper is on a ListView item. When you tap the ListView item, it flips over to display additional options. This doesnt happen anymore when I use @BindView to initialize my ViewFlipper, and the app doesnt crash, so no relevant logs. Code:

```
public class DepartmentListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
String[] departments;
@BindView(R.id.view_flipper_2) ViewFlipper flipper;
@BindView(R.id.departmentName) TextView departmentName;
@BindView(R.id.departmentOverviewButton) Button overViewButton;
@BindView(R.id.organizationalStructureButton) Button structureButton;

public DepartmentListAdapter(Context context, String[] departments){

    this.context = context;
    this.departments = departments;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return departments.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return departments[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view;

    if(convertView == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.department_list_item, parent, false);

    }else{
        view = convertView;
    }

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    //this gets set
    departmentName.setText(departments[position]);

    flipper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //this effect is gone, not sure onClick is even being called
            AnimationFactory.flipTransition(flipper, AnimationFactory.FlipDirection.TOP_BOTTOM, 90);
        }

    });

    overViewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "DO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    structureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "DS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
           context, R.anim.listview_slide);

    view.startAnimation(animation);

    return view;
}

}
```